# Swift pushViewController Works on iPad but not iPhone

Tags: ios, swift

I have no idea what is happening but my code stopped working on iPhone but works fine on iPad.  (Using Xcode 10 and Swift 4)

I first check for the data and if not set it transfers to the ConfigVC.

Nothing happens on the simulator for any phone settings.  I went so far as to reinstall my system software and Xcode.

I use this same approach on other apps and it is fine.  For some strange reason it just stopped working on this app.

```
func dataCheck(){

    // make sure the required data is set 
    if User.getInfo() == nil || Index.getAll() == nil  {

        let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Config", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ConfigVC") as? ConfigVC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)

    }
}
```

The code shows it just ending.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint inside the if, will it ever get hit?

Comment: What debugging have you done? What does the posted code actually do on an iPhone? Is `self` inside a nav controller?

Comment: I am not good at the debugging stuff. I am a rookie.  yes the breakpoint gets hit.

Comment: it does nothing. it just stays on the Launchscreen

Comment: change `self.navigationController?` to `self.navigationController!` and try if crashed post it  ?

Comment: no effect with changing ? to !

Comment: where you call `dataCheck` ??

Comment: override func viewDidLoad()

Comment: first thing called

Comment: see answer below also i guees you need to put your code inside`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: The issue should be in the calling place. `dataCheck` should be called after finishing the parent. then it should call withing main thread. you may be calling it with some other thread. some times some devices on some OSes can work, but you cannot gurentee that.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to push/present a vc while the current isn't yet loaded inside `viewDidLoad` so move the call to `dataCheck` inside `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear`

Comment: it appears it is a conflict with the SideMenu and NavBar? do idea what is happening or why it works on iPad and not iPhone?